# Does NextJS Fast Refresh work on non-component files?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a reducer file that goes like this:

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.ACTION_1: ...,
    default: ...
  }
}
```

when compiling, I got this warning on the console:

```
warn  - my-reducer.js
Anonymous arrow functions cause Fast Refresh to not preserve local component state.
Please add a name to your function, for example:

Before
export default () => <div />;

After
const Named = () => <div />;
export default Named;
```

According to next's docs, Fast Refresh is only used on React components
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/fast-refresh

Does this mean that I can ignore this error, or do I have to refactor my reducers to use named functions?

Comment: There is some talk amongst the React maintainers to deprecate exported anonymous functions. With React Refresh reliant upon a component name to refresh, the best practice is to name all your functions (including non components). When you move to a testing environment anonymous functions will be indiscernible from others, for example: `<_default />`.

Comment: On a side note, you may run into issues with your Redux reducer state because it’s an anonymous function. As a force of habit, I always recommend naming your functions regardless. It’ll be more apparent to its usage when it has a descriptive name: `userReducer` or  `postReducer` and so on.